# Which word I can use nearly like "whenever" in this situation?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request

Causally asking help,

> If you go to London, purchase things and bring me.

Situation is I don't know if he is going or not. I'm not stress him to go. If he go, then I'm asking help to purchase things and bring them to me.

I am trying to use the words "whenever you go", but in the dictionary, 'whenever' means 'every time that' and I'm asking for one time help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is hard to understand, @loops, but I think you are asking for a word that means "if you go to London, then that time ... " as opposed to "every time you go to London..."

The answer is that in most varieties of English there is not one word that conveys the meaning. I would say

> If you happen to go London, ...

or

> If you go to London, ...

("When you go to London, ..." would imply that I know for sure that you are going there).

However, there are some varieties of English where "whenever" can be used in this way. So to me

> Whenever you go to London, ...

means "every time you go". But I have heard people from Northern Ireland, for example, using it to mean exactly what you want to say.